# warning Nested block is redundant no-lone-blocks

Tags: reactjs, nested, eslint, braces

```
 {i18n.language === "fa" ? (
        <div className="mb-3 fff">
          <IoIosArrowDroprightCircle
            className="swiper-navigation_prev"
            onClick={handlePrev}
          />
          <IoIosArrowDropleftCircle
            className="swiper-navigation_next"
            onClick={handleNext}
          />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="mb-3 fff">
          <IoIosArrowDropleftCircle
            className="swiper-navigation_prev"
            onClick={handlePrev}
          />
          <IoIosArrowDroprightCircle
            className="swiper-navigation_next"
            onClick={handleNext}
          />
        </div>
      )}
```

It's part of a 2-language project in React. There's no extra braces, I removed parenthesis and it doesn't help too.